# Metadata Filter in Data Pump API

Tags: oracle, datapump

How to exclude all INDEX,GRANT,SYNONYM,CONSTRAINT while exporting data using Oracle Data Pump API (DBMS_DATAPUMP package)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
expdp help=yes
```

Gives you the options. You might find the "EXCLUDE" option worth looking at.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_legacy.htm#SUTIL962

```
EXCLUDE=view,package,function,constraint,ref_constraint,grant....
```